# WiFi becomes slow when the Bluetooth is turned on (Intel Wireless-N 7265)

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth, 22.04, intel

I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed on my Lenovo Thinkpad L450 with **Intel Wireless-N 7265** network card and I'm experiencing huge connection slowdown when the Bluetooth is turned on.
I guess that this problem is caused by both WiFi and Bluetooth running on same frequency (2.4 GHz).
I found config file for my kernel driver in /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf, but I don't know what to add here to fix this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

This will create another conf file that will disable BT coex feature.

That should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the issue.